# Add hysteresis on scaled range of values

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

From [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/93119) answer, the goal of the `resample` function below is to add an hysteresis to the readings of an ADC channel (0..1024, 10-bit) in order to show stable lower resolution values (0..127, 7-bit) on a display.

Here my current working code:

```
#define ADC_HYSTERESIS 4

int Menu::resample(int adc, int *value)
{
    int lowerTest = (*value << 3) - ADC_HYSTERESIS;
    int higherTest = ((*value + 1) << 3) + ADC_HYSTERESIS;

    int lowerOutput = (adc + ADC_HYSTERESIS) >> 3;
    int higherOutput = (adc - ADC_HYSTERESIS) >> 3;

    if (adc < lowerTest) *value = lowerOutput;
    else if (adc >= higherTest) *value = higherOutput;

    if (*value > 127) *value = 127;
    if (*value < 0) *value = 0;
    return *value;
}
```

**Note**: instead of using a `static` variable for `value` I use a member one. Example:

```
slider.value = resample(adc, &slider.lastValue, slider.min, slider.max);
```

where:

```
typedef struct
{
    int value;
    int lastValue;
    int min;
    int max;
} slider_t;

slider_t slider;
```

I want to improve the suggested code to use a reduced range of output values (between `min` and `max`). It's guaranteed that `min < max` and `max < 128`.

If `min` was `0` it would be easy: replace the 3-bits shifting with a division or a multiplication for `1024 / max`.
But I'm having issues about how handle the lower rail (aka `min`).
This is my attempt:

```
int Menu::resample(int adc, int *value, byte min, byte max)
{    
    // sanity checks omitted: min < max and max < 128

    double m = 1015.0 / (max - min); // 1015 = 1023 - 8 (1 LSB of low-res output)
                                     // otherwise it reaches 126 even if max = 127
    int q = min << 3;

    int lowerTest = (q + *value * m) - ADC_HYSTERESIS;
    int higherTest = (q + (*value + 1) * m) + ADC_HYSTERESIS;

    int lowerOutput = min + (adc + ADC_HYSTERESIS) / m;
    int higherOutput = min + (adc - ADC_HYSTERESIS) / m;

    if (adc < lowerTest) *value = lowerOutput;
    else if (adc >= higherTest) *value = higherOutput;

    if (*value > max) *value = max;
    if (*value < min) *value = min;
    return *value;
}
```

The behavior is quite correct: it remaps the ADC input (`0..1023`) to the desired output range (`min..max`) but the hysteresis no longer works. It's enough a change of 1-bit of ADC input to trigger a change of the output value (of course at switching points).